# Error expected primary-expression before 'int' en funciones con arreglo

Tags: c

este programa se encarga de agregar un elemento. Estoy probando con void, pero al momento de compilar, me marca

`[Error] expected primary-expression before 'int'`

pero, he agreado de todo y no puedo. Ojalá puedan ayudarme.
Es la primera vez que trabajo con funciones y realmente no sé cómo es que funcionan con arrays, dado que estoy en mis primeros semestres de la carrera.

````
 int n;
 int array[200];
 void agregarelemento(int x,int k,int j);
 
 int main (){
 
 printf("Ingresa el numero de elementos del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingresa el elemento numero %d del arreglo: ", (i+1) );
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    
    printf("buscar arreglo");
    agregarelemento (int x,int k, int j);
    
}

void agregarelemento(int x,int k,int j)
{
    int a,i;
{
         int  j ;
    j = n-1;
    while (j >= k)  {
        array [j+1] =  array [j];
        j--;
    }
    array[k] = x;
    n++;
    
}

for (i=0; i <10; i=i+1)
for (j=0; j <10; j=j+1)
if ( array[i] < array[j] )
{
a= array[i];
array[i]=array[j];
array[j]=a;
}

/* Desplegando el contenido del archivo */
for(i=0; i <n+1; i=i+1)
printf("%3d", array[i]);

return;
}```
````

Comment: C++ o C? No es lo mismo... recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que haga falta, usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas.

Comment: Las funciones no se llaman asi `agregarelemento (int x,int k, int j)`, solo colocas los parametros sin los tipos.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los parámetros sin los tipos?